# iPython autoreload magic function not found

Tags: ipython

I have used the following scripts in an iPython notebook to enable autoreload.

```
import autoreload

%autoreload
```

The import works find but the magic function throws the following error:

```
ERROR: Line magic function `%autoreload` not found.
```

Here are the current version settings as per the notebook 'about' section:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 22 2015, 19:33:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3]
IPython 4.1.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
```

Any pointers on what the issue could be would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you are using this in IPython notebook

This command will load autoreload:

```
%load_ext autoreload
```

This line will reload pandas (replace pandas with the module name you would like to reload) every time code is run:

```
%aimport pandas
```

If you wish to remove pandas from reloading every time you run code then,
this line will stop pandas from reloading:

```
%aimport -pandas
```

Include `%autoreload` at the top the cell for the magic to happen!

[autoreload Reference](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html?highlight=autoreload#autoreload)